# Chrome: Address bar autocomplete changes sporadically

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

I frequently search Wikipedia on Chrome by opening a new tab, typing just "w" into the address bar, and then using tab-to-search with autocomplete to open the Wikipedia search.

I occasionally run into the problem where Chrome will arbitrarily rerank the autocomplete and no longer place Wikipedia as the top result, even though Wikipedia is by far the website beginning with "w" that I use the most. This appears to be based on Chrome sometimes including the "www" part of *every* URL as part of the ranking, at which point "w" will just autocomplete to my most used website.

Is it possible to force Chrome to avoid using the "www" portion of the URLs in the autocomplete ranking or to dictate that Wikipedia be ranked at the top for certain automcomplete?

Answer (score 0):

##### Chrome's Search Support

Chrome natively provides support for multiple alternative search engines in addition to any default that is already set.

Therefore, rather than leveraging Chrome's address autocomplete to predict Wikipedia whenever you type a `w`, make it a permanent rule that any terms that follow `w+space` are to be searched in  Wikipedia.

###### Search Wikipedia using <kbd>W</kbd>

1. In chrome's **address bar** type `chrome://settings/searchEngines` then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
2. In the **Site search** section click `Add`
3. Then in the **Add search Engine** dialog put the following:

```
Engine:    Wikipedia 
Shortcut:  w
URL:       http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&search=%s
```

4. Then click `Add`

Now whenever you want to search using Wikipedia you will simply put
<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>[string]

e.g. "w babylon" will bring up https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon

[image]